# Deeplab: how to separate segmentation of overlapping objects?

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation, deeplab

I'm using the tensorflow deeplab to dolphins segmentation, according to the following images.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/307129/57341524-20c9f580-7111-11e9-9a98-641695ab214d.jpg

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/307129/57341527-26bfd680-7111-11e9-9511-26ddce1220e3.png

However, the tool does not return the separate segmentation of overlapping animals. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiago Zis.. I went through your question.. As per your need, you are in need of separation between the instances of dolphin, which is somewhat beyond the scope of Deeplab. Still it can be done by training the model with a separation layer in middle and when doing so, you need to make sure that you see the ignore_labels. Else you can go in looking for Instance Segmentation.

Comment: The model was trained with the separation layer "ignore_labels", but did not solve the problem. I will research more about instance segmentation. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @TiagoZis ignore_labels is by default used in Deeplab, wherein white lines are present to differentiate between the classes. In your dataset, check out if something relevant is available, since your use case wants to differentiate between the instances of the same class.